# Why is Logger most of time static?

Tags: java, oop, logging, static

Why is it considered "best practice" in java to use `Logger` with `static` as:

```
public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(....)
```

I can't figure the reson why. If I use one logger instance and pass it by constructor, it shouldn't affect performance.

Can anybody explain why? Is it better then DI? If so, why? There are lot of opinions. Or is it just "because of java way"?

Comment: They follow the [Factory design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)).

Comment: I personally very rarely consider anything with `static` a "best practice". I prefer to setup logging with Dependency Injection - but DI often works best when the system was designed as such from the start and the approach shown is much simpler to us as a one-off, retrofit, or use without needing all the extra 'work'.

Comment: It's just a disguise to an ugly global variable representing a singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent multiple instances being created needlessly. Generally, a single `Logger` is sufficient because it writes to a single logical location (which might be multiple physical output streams). If you're passing a `Logger` to a method, it's presumably to programatically handle the logging. Instead, I suggest you prefer the logger's own configuration mechanism to enable and disable the messaging.

Comment: An IoC can just as easily "prevent multiple instances being created needlessly". Also the OP says "If I use *one logger instance* and pass it by constructor, it shouldn't affect performance atc..."

Comment: @user2864740 Only if you assume IoC is free (and was available when the `Logger` was implemented), similarly with garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

I'm arguing that you can achieve the same results with using **setter injection** and **Dependency Injection Container**.

You can still have very simple logging, it just isn't static and therefore can be configured and changed in the DI Container, without configuring some global static state of some global static factory, that is usually really hard to test and maintain.

However, I know that making it static is pragmatic. I'm just arguing that doing it the DI way is cleaner.

Comment: How does this answer **why** `Logger` is *frequently* `static`?

Comment: Let me rephrase: I'm sitting right next to Snurka Bill, we're arguing about it. I'm arguing the DI way and we're trying to figure out if there is any really good reason to make it static. The question wasn't phrased ideally before.

Answer (score 1):

That's because doing logging properly is very difficult. [Consider the single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle):

> In object-oriented programming, the single responsibility principle states that every class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility.

However, if you think about it, code that manages logging is *never going to be the primary responsibility of a class.* The class is going to do what it does, and then you might add some logging statements that are a **second responsibility** of the class. How can this be resolved?

One way is to use [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) and reflection to go through your code and try to log activities as they happen, but this is ugly and needs to be tacked on to the language. Another way would be to add `Logger` objects to the construction of classes, but this has a few drawbacks:

1. You can only do this without adding *lots* of boilerplate if you are using a DI framework
2. You still have to configure the `Logger`'s name somehow, which means the injection now depends on the class that it's being injected into.
3. Again, if you aren't using a DI framework, then you have to somehow maintain access to the same `Logger` object at object creation, or you end up creating many duplicate objects that cost memory, for no advantage, which is even more boilerplate code.

So, what to do? The *easiest* way would be to allow all classes to have static access to a `Logger` object. SLF4J provides this mechanism with `LoggerFactory.getLogger()`, as you correctly point out. It's one line of code that can enable fully customizable behavior within all of your classes to use logging functionality, using the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)). You don't have to worry about injection, about reflection, about configuring AOP; it's simple, straightforward, and works.

Comment: Logging can be just as easily handled with DI. As such this does not answer the question or address the OPs statement: "If I use one logger instance and pass it by constructor, it shouldn't affect performance atc..."

Answer (score 0):

private - so that no other class can hijack your logger

static - so there is only one logger instance per class, also avoiding attempts to serialize loggers

final - no need to change the logger over the lifetime of the class

However there is an interesting exception to these rules:

protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

The former way allows you to use the same logger name (name of the actual class) in all classes throughout the inheritance hierarchy. So if Bar extends Foo, both will log to Bar logger. Some find it more intuitive.

The advantage of the non-static form is that you can declare it in an (abstract) base class like follows without worrying that the right classname will be used

However its disadvantage is obviously that a whole new logger instance will be created for every instance of the class.

On the other hand, if you obtain the logger by a factory which in turn may cache the already-instantiated loggers, then using the non-static form won't add that much overhead. Log4j for example has a LogManager for this purpose.

protected Log log = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());